# Combine multiple tokenizers in Solr

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to combine `LetterTokenizerFactory` with `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` and not able to find how to do it without copying content using `copyField`.

Let me describe my idea:

- I have two entries in text, e.g. H&M and Hewlett-Packard
- User should be able to find H&M entering `h&m` - I use `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` for this purpose, no need to split tokens on special chars
- User should be able to find Hewlett-Packard entering 'packard' - `LetterTokenizerFactory` serves this case, tokens are splitted on special characters
- Now I want to combine both this tokenizers

How can I achieve it without declaring 2 different types with different tokenizer factories and then copying value to field with second type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory as the main tokenizer, and then add the [WordDelimiterGraphFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterGraphFilter) to split your tokens further up into smaller tokens.

From the example for the WordDelimiterGraphFilter (previously named WordDelimiterFilter, but that's deprecated now - so the name will depend on which Solr version you're using):

> Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot"

That would allow packard to match hewlett. Be advised that this will also allow 'm' to match `h&m`, since you're splitting on non-alphanumeric characters. You can either use the `protected` setting for the filter to specify a list of words that should not be touched, or even better, if you want everything with `&` to remain untouched, use the `types` parameter to redefine what type `&` should be considered as.

Comment: thanks, it could work! but I was hoping to find a way to always have additionally original token with special character, even if I haven't specified any exceptional symbols. e.g. "hot-spot" -> "hot", "spot", "hot-spot" ; "h&m" -> "h", "m", "h&m", etc.

Comment: I've just noted option `preserveOriginal` to keep original value as token aswell